# heroku : Failed to fetch

Tags: heroku

I have a React front end application with a node back end.

When I run the application locally all works well, by that I mean I am able to post and receive data from my endpoint, when I deploy the code on Heroku I am not longer able to post to the back end.

It seems that Heroku doesn't include the back end node when publishing the application

P.s this my first post, so apologies if I didn't provide the right info off the bat.

Comment: Can you provide more info, maybe some code snippet that is causing problem and how you are deploying to Heroku.

Comment: Sure one sec, I am using automaic deployment (git) via heroku so when I push to git it will redply in Heroku. I don't know where the problem is coming from, however, when I inspect https://yana-scheduler.herokuapp.com/ I can't see the local host 8000 which should be the back end node JS

Comment: I found the issue, was the scripts in my package Json